# Perl Test::More Before Block

Tags: perl

Does Test::More have some sort of mechanism to run a block of code before every subtest?  I'm finding myself writing the same arrangements on every test and I would like to make my life easier by putting it in a before block or something?  I looked at the perldocs, but I didn't see anything specifically built for this?

Comment: Isn't it considered an important part of tests to have completely independent units? Anyway. You could always use functions that wrap your testvalues and pass them as parameters to `Test::More`s functions.

Comment: Perhaps you could leverage `subtest`.

Comment: A before block that I'm used to is excecute before every single test, so it is completely independent. As a temporary solution I've created a function called arrange() that does this for me.  However, I was trying to leverage the framework.

Comment: There is also [Test::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Class) which has helper functions, relative test counting/adjustment, and entry and exit points for code. It's very nice but should be understood thoroughly before being chosen; sub attributes and inheritance make it a little tricky depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather easy to do yourself:

```
use Hook::LexWrap qw( wrap );

wrap $_, pre => sub { ... }
   for qw( is ok ... );
```

[Hook::LexWrap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Hook::LexWrap)

Answer (score 1):

`Test::More`'s tests seem to run `Test::Builder::Module::builder` before every test. You could replace that implementation with this.

```
{   package Test::Builder::Module;
    my $old_imp = \&Test::Builder::Module:builder;
    no warnings 'redefine';
    sub builder { 
        Mypackage::setup_test();
        goto &$old_imp;
    }
}
```

And if that seems too dangerous, it actually calls it like this:

```
sub is ($$;$) {
    my $tb = Test::More->builder;

    return $tb->is_eq(@_);
}
```

So, you could just push-in an implementation of `builder` for `Test::More`, since it calls the one in its parent class:

```
{   package Test::More; 
    sub builder { 
        &stuff_I_want_to_do;
        my $inv = shift;
        return $inv->SUPER::builder( @_ );
        # OR return Test::Builder->new;   
    }
}
```